# Cisco IOS XR version clarification

Tags: cisco, ios

I've run across [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/products_security_advisory09186a0080b7f18f.shtml#@ID) cisco advisory

It says:

> This bug was introduced in Cisco IOS
>   XR Software release 3.6.2 and is fixed
>   with SMU hfr-k9sec-3.6.2.CSCtd74795.
>   The SMU ID for this fix in 3.6.2 is
>   AA03656. This vulnerability has been
>   fixed in 3.8.3, 3.9.1, and 4.0.0 for
>   customers running later software
>   versions. Software version 3.7 is not
>   affected by this vulnerability.

I'm trying to figure out something, according to this, 3.6.2 is vulnerable unless fixed with the mentioned SMU.

What about versions such as:

- 3.6.1
- 3.6.0
- 3.5.4
  and earlier... are they also vulnerable?

Also, it says it was fixed in 3.8.3 and 3.9.1, why do they also mention 3.9.1, isnt 3.9.1 > 3.8.3 so its obvious that it is also fixed in 3.9.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking a reasonable question.  The first thing to understand is that Cisco's software development often happens in parallel branches<sup>1</sup>, with respect to where features are committed.

In this case, a developer simultaneously committed vulnerable code into 3.6.2 and 3.7.1; that vulnerable code escaped Q/A testing and was released on CCO.  All software released in those branches *after*<sup>2</sup> 3.6.2 and 3.7.1 was vulnerable<sup>3</sup> until the fix was committed simultaneously into 3.8.3, 3.9.1 and 4.0.0

---

### END-NOTES:

1. See Jeff Atwood's blog [Coding Horror: Software Branching and Parrallel Universes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/software-branching-and-parallel-universes.html)
2. Versions 3.5.4, 3.6.0, 3.6.1 should not be vulnerable as they were not mentioned in the notification
3. Versions 3.8.0, 3.8.1, 3.8.2, and 3.9.0 also contain the vulnerable code